# Find the limit without the use of derivatives

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{x\to (-3)}\frac {2{x^3}+3{x^2}-11x-6}{{(x+3)^2}({x^2} - 9)}$
  I have managed to do some simplifying but not enough to actually find it.

Yeah I have already found that $2{x^3}+3{x^2}-11x-6=(x+3)(x-2)(2x+1)$ and one $(x+3)$ is gone, but there are still two $(x+3)$ that nullify the denominator for x=-3

Comment: Can you show us what simplifying you have done? For example, have you managed to factorise $2x^3+3x^2-11x-6$?

Comment: People seem to be answering exactly what I have done but I still can't find the value of the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Use that your numerator can be written as $$(x-2) (x+3) (2 x+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a situation where numerator of limit is non-zero and the denominator is 0 then the limit doesn't exists.

Comment: Oh that cleared things up for me. Thank you guys and sorry for posting without studying the subject thoroughly at first.

Comment: it holds as a general rule. If you don't cancel the fraction then it would still be in $0/0$ form and this rule says nothing about that. example would be $\cos x/x$

Comment: you are misunderstanding. Take this case, in final form We get $25/0$ which isn't an indeterminate from. Hence the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you have a rough idea of why this works? I apologise for the misconceptions, but this idea comes off as 'hard to prove' for me.

Comment: It is easy to prove, say limit is of form $lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ say the $f(a)=M\neq 0$ and $lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)=0$ then $lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{M}{g(x)}$ now using the fact the limit of g(x) is 0 can you show that limit of $1/g(x)$ won't exist? (using the epsilon delta definition)

Answer (score 0):

So you have this fraction:

$$\frac{(x-2)(x+3)(2x+1)}{(x+3)^2(x^2-9)}$$

Factorise $x^2-9$ as $(x+3)(x-3)$ (using the difference of two squares), and now you can cancel an $x+3$:

$$\frac{(x-2)(x+3)(2x+1)}{(x+3)^2(x+3)(x-3)}$$
$$= \frac{(x-2)(2x+1)}{(x+3)^2(x-3)}$$

We have removed all the removable discontinuities by cancelling the fraction.
As this function is a rational function, the discontinuity occurs when the denominator is $0$. Substituting $x = -3$ into the denominator gives $0$, so the limit does not exist there.

Answer (score 0):

If you evaluate the numerator at $-3$, you get $0$. This means that $x+3$ is a factor; with synthetic division
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc|c}
   & 2          &  3 & -11 & -6 \\
-3 & \downarrow & -6 &   9 &  6\\ \hline
   & 2          & -3 &  -2 &  0
\end{array}
$$
you see that the numerator factors as $(x+3)(2x^2-3x-2)$. The factor $2x^2-3x-2$ doesn't vanish for $x=-3$, so you're done. Now your limit can be written, with an easy factorization of the denominator
$$
\lim_{x\to-3}\frac{(x+3)(2x^2-3x-2)}{(x+3)^3(x-3)}=
\lim_{x\to-3}\frac{2x^2-3x-2}{(x+3)^2(x-3)}=
\lim_{x\to-3}\frac{1}{(x+3)^2}\frac{2x^2-3x-2}{x-3}
$$
The second fraction evaluates as $-8/3$ for $x=-3$. Therefore you can conclude that the function is negative in a punctured neighborhood of $-3$. Finally
$$
\lim_{x\to -3}\frac {2{x^3}+3{x^2}-11x-6}{{(x+3)^2}({x^2} - 9)}=-\infty
$$